# Finding a dimension of cubic polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

> The first question: find a dimension of cubic polynomials $p(x)$, such that $p(7) = 0$.

I got dimension $= 3$.

> The second question: find a dimension of cubic polynomials $p(x)$, such that $p(7) = 0 \land p(5) = 0$.

I couldn't find a vector that satisfies both of equations. Please help!

Comment: Hint: $p(x)=(x-7)\cdot (x-5)\cdot q(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $V = \mathbb{R}_{\leq 3}[x]$ the vector space of cubic polynomials. We know that $\dim V = 4$.

1. Define a linear map $L \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $L(p) = p(7)$. This map is onto (we have $L(a) = a$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ when we think of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ both as a zero degree polynomial and as a real number) and so $\dim \ker L = \dim V - \dim \operatorname{Im}(L) = 4 - 1 = 3$.
2. Define a linear map $L \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $L(p) = (p(5),p(7))$. This map is again onto (we have $L \left( -\frac{x-7}{2} \right) = (1,0)$ and $L \left(\frac{x-5}{2} \right) = (0, 1)$) and so $\dim \ker L = \dim V - \dim \operatorname{Im}(L) = 4 - 2 = 2$.